# I get "Segmentation Fault Error" in cython extension for python. How could I fix that?

Tags: python, c++, csv, cython, fstream

I try to use the example of cython code for reading from files [cythonized reading](http://www.code-corner.de/?p=183)

```
from libc.stdio cimport *

cdef extern from "stdio.h":
    #FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode )
    FILE *fopen(const char *, const char *)
    #int fclose ( FILE * stream )
    int fclose(FILE *)
    #ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
    ssize_t getline(char **, size_t *, FILE *)

def read_file(filename):
    filename_byte_string = filename.encode("UTF-8")
    cdef char* fname = filename_byte_string

    cdef FILE* cfile
    cfile = fopen(fname, "rb")
    if cfile == NULL:
        raise IOError(2, "No such file or directory: '%s'" % filename)

    cdef char * line = NULL
    cdef size_t l = 0
    cdef ssize_t read

    while True:
        read = getline(&line, &l, cfile)
        if read == -1: break

        yield line

    fclose(cfile)

    return []
```

And I use this function with:

```
iterator = read_file(my_filename)
next(iterator)
```

After reading of a big amount of csv files I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". This function "read_file" reads files in an equivalent way like a standard open(filename, 'rb') of python, but a lot faster than one. I have also tried C++ extension with such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> readFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> fileStrings;
    std::ifstream myfile(fileName.c_str());

    if(!myfile)
    {
        std::cout<<"Error opening output file"<< std::endl;
        return fileStrings;
    }
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if(line.empty()) continue;
        std::istringstream is(line);
        fileStrings.push_back(is.str());
    }
    return fileStrings;
}
```

And in my pyx file:

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference, preincrement
cdef extern from "read_file.h":
    vector[string] readFile(string user_name) nogil

def readFileIterator(string fileName):
    file_lines_list=[]
    fileLines = readFile(fileName)
    iterator = fileLines.begin()
    while iterator != fileLines.end():
        file_lines_list.append(dereference(iterator))
        preincrement(iterator)
    return iter(file_lines_list)
```

It seems that such way is not equivalent to standard python's reading, because I have a plenty of additional errors during reading of csv (something with non standard symbols).
So the question is: What is the proper way for reading of files in cython which could be interfaced as standard reading in pure python? Why do I get "Segmentation Fault error"?

Comment: Compile your cython extension with `-g -Wall`. If possible, compile Python with them too

Comment: Ok, I'll try to compile it setup.py by addition of extra_compile_args = ["-g", "-Wall"], but how could it help?

Comment: Then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)